# Will the following code work to check if the contents of array of objects equals to each other?

Tags: java, object

I have this college class in which i want to see if teachers and students are equal

```
public class college
{
    public boolean equals()        
    {        
        boolean isEqual = true;        
        int i = 0;                          
        while(students[i] != null || teacher[i] != null)        
        {        
            if(!students[i].equals(teacher[i]))        
            {        
                 isEqual = false;        
            }        
           i++;        
        }        
        return isEqual;                                         
    }
}
```

Comment: on what property basis you want to check there equality ? Based on that you might need to override compare()

Comment: You need to check length of the arrays before checking the values. If length of the arrays are different, your code will crash with OutOfBoundException.

Comment: Also, you should not run while loop and check for null values. You are assuming, that null value is at the end of the array. That may not be the true.

Comment: You better run 'for' loop instead of the 'while'

Comment: This implies that an instance of `Submarine` *can* be equal to an instance of `FighterJet`. Usually (but not necessarily) that implies also that either `fighterJet instanceof Submarine` or `submarine instanceof FighterJet`or both will be true … and this does not make much sense, usually!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding 1 length check + changing your code to use a for loop.

1)

```
isEqual = (submarine.length == fighterJet.length);
```

So if length differs you won't go into the loop.

---

2)

```
 for(int i = 0; isEqual && i < submarine.length; i++)
```

This loop will exit loop upon non equal value.

---

New code -

```
public boolean equals()        
{        
    boolean isEqual = (submarine.length == fighterJet.length);       
    for(int i = 0 ; isEqual && i < submarine.length ; i ++){
        if(!submarine[i].equals(fighterJet[i]))        
        {        
             isEqual = false;        
        }           
    }        
    return isEqual;                                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if arrays are same in length, then you create simple for loop and check if values at same index are identical. If one of combinations is not identical you break loop and return false

```
boolean isEqual = true;                          
    if(subamrine.length == fighterJet.length){
        for(int i=0 ; i < subamrine.length ; i++){
            if(subamrine[i] != fighterJet[i]){
                isEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        isEqual = false;
    }
    return isEqual;
```

Comment: This looks good but what if I dont want to use break? Im not allowed to use break.

Comment: Delete it. It is just for speed to stop loop